# How can I make background music for android project

Tags: java, android, media, background-music

I'm making a small android app like image below:
[image]

I have a sound button. All I want is background music will play across all activity and when I click on sound button, music will stop. Or click to play music again.

I dont know how to make it. PLease help me! or give me link to refer.

I'd gladly appreciate your help it Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried overriding the Application and using the MediaPlayer in there? Or using a service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing BG Music Across Activities in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097909/playing-bg-music-across-activities-in-android)

Comment: ^ Please read through *all* the answers there and take the accepted answer with a grain of salt (based on the comments). See also the example at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#appcomp.

Comment: Possibly a better duplicate (with a better answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service?rq=1

Comment: I tried service. But it set what activity play music and what activity stop music..All i want is click the button and music background will be played or stopped

Answer (score 3):

Hi please Follow below steps

1. initialized
   MusicPlayer object when your app starts `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);`

set this in your button's click event.

1. Start it by `mediaPlayer.start();`

3.Stop it by `mediaPlayer.stop();`

but when you stopping mediaPlayer before that just check `mediaPlayer.isPlaying()` with if Condition. then Stop. else error thrown.

or follow this Example [Turorial Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App)

Answer (score 2):

In order for media to be played in the background of your app location when the user is interacting with it you must start a Service from your application's main activity and the service shall contain all the methods related to playback. To allow activity to interact with the service, a service connection is also required. In short, we need to implement a bounded service.

Refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App

Comment: mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinderbinder).getService();

Comment: Nothing wrong with that line. You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988852/background-music-for-game-app-that-will-play-to-all-class. Code is present.