# Android - play background music that will play across all activities

Tags: android, service, background, media, audio

I have been researching for hours to no avail. I'm trying to implement a simple background music to my app that will play across all activities and pause whenever the app is minimised.

However nothing seems to be working for me.

I have tried read and visited the following.

[Android background music service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service)

[Play background music in all activities of Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579765/play-background-music-in-all-activities-of-android-app)

[Background music for game app that will play to all class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988852/background-music-for-game-app-that-will-play-to-all-class)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App

And many many others but there is always one thing that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone send an example of a 3 activity app that has background audio through all activities and pauses the music when the app is not visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a base activity and extend all other other activities from base activity and play bg music or whatever you want

```
public class BaseActivty extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
// pause music
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
// play music
    }
}

public class FirstActivty extends BaseActivty{

// perform other stuff here
}
```

hope that will help you...

Comment: So the base activity is responsible for initiating the service and controlling the music?? It can't be that simple can it?

Comment: That's working really well now except for a stutter between activities. Is there a way of getting rid of that?

Comment: sorry for late response i was away... for this problem you can start a service and it will solve your problem..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had managed to solve the problem and all is working perfectly. I can't believe how simple it all ended up being.

Comment: Still have problem here. Problem is when you finish FisrtActivity. The method onDestroy of BaseActivty will be called and stop music.
Question is : How to finish FristActivity without call onDestroy method of BaseActivity??