# Android - Pause/Resume music across all Activities

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I'm working on a game with a `MainActivity` which opens activities with the game levels. Each of the level activities inherits a `BaseActivity`.

`MainActivity` never finishes. All the levels open on top of it.

I want to start my music in the `MainActivity` and keep it playing throughout the rest of the application.

The catch is that I want the `Service` to pause the music when the app goes to the background.

I've created a `MusicService` which plays the music through the `MediaPlayer` like so -

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.setVolume(100,100);
    player.start();
}
```

I'm confused about where to pause the music. The `Service` is started from the `MainActivity` but I want to be able to also pause it even when the app is paused while on any Level activity. Can I communicate with the `Service` through any `Activity`?

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032290/android-play-background-music-that-will-play-across-all-activities) but I don't want my music to stop and then restart every time I destroy and create a Level activity.

Comment: You can create notification For example [http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/android-custom-notification-tutorial/](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/android-custom-notification-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use EventBus

Gradle dependancy -

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
```

In your main activity onCreate

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

In your main activity onDestroy

```
EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
```

In your main activity write method like below. This method will always call when you post your event from any activity

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onPauseEvent(event: PauseEvent) {

}
```

And last step post your event from any activity or non activity classes

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new PauseEvent("delete"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` and register it, in your service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        registerReceiver(new Player(), new IntentFilter(App.Communication.Player));

    return START_STICKY;
}

private class Player extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            int action = extras.getInt(App.Communication.IntentAction);
            if(action == App.Communication.ActionStart){

                isPlaying = true;

                String url = extras.getString(App.Communication.URL);
             //Start player from url
            }
            else if(action == App.Communication.ActionPlay ){
                urlPlayer.start();
            }
            else if(action == App.Communication.ActionPause ){
                //Pause Player
            }
            else if(action == App.Communication.ActionStop ){
                //Stop player
            }
            else if(action == App.Communication.ActionSeekForward ){
                //Seek Forward
            }
            else if(action == App.Communication.ActionSeekBack ){
                //Seek Back}

        }
    }
```

Create a simple App class to hold some static values

```
public class App  {

    public class Communication{
        public static final String Player = "Player";
        public static final int ActionStart = 0;
        public static final int ActionPlay = 1;
        public static final int ActionPause = 2;
        public static final int ActionStop = 3;
        public static final int ActionSeekForward = 4;
        public static final int ActionSeekBack = 5;
        public static final int ActionPlayRadio = 6;


    }
}
```

And lastly in any `Activity` simple call the `BroadCast`. For example to play

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(App.Communication.Player);
    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    mBundle.putInt(App.Communication.IntentAction,App.Communication.ActionPause);

    intent.putExtras(mBundle);
    mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```